# Subquery in Linq to NHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, subquery, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a query by Linq in NHibernate 3.1:

```
public IList<Person> Search()
{
    var sub_q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>().Where(x => x.Id < 6).Select(x => x.Id);

    var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>();
    q = q.Where(x => sub_q.Contains(x.Id));

    return q.ToList<Person>();
}
```

Id column is primary key in Database
This sub-query does not work. Count of my query with sub-query equals by count of my query without use sub-query.

Count of my query whit sub-query    : 52 //Correct count is 5

Count of my query without sub-query : 52

Why?

**Updated:**
My problem resolved by rename `x` variable in sub_q to `xx`

```
 var sub_q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>().Where(xx => xx.Id < 6).Select(xx => xx.Id);
```

Why?

Comment: Have your tried this against v3.2 or even the trunk as the Linq provider has come along way since V3.1? This may be an old bug that has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Apply ToList method on sub_q might resolve your issue because there might be a problem of **linq differed** execution..

code is like

```
var sub_q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>()
                   .Where(x => x.Id < 6).Select(x => x.Id).ToList(); 
    var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>();    
 q = q.Where(x => sub_q.Contains(x.Id));
```

**OR** you can try

```
q = q.Where(x => (SessionInstance.Query<Person>()
                 .Where(x => x.Id < 6).Select(x => x.Id)).Contains(x.Id));
```

not sure about above second soltuion

but i think you must need to do `ToList()` to resolve issue of differed execution..

Comment: It is not suitable for performance. This is not a sub-query. For your solution sub-query is a List<Person>, so do not use from sub-query and it work 100 % . Performance is important for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolved by rename `x` variable in sub_q to `xx`

```
 var sub_q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>().Where(xx => xx.Id < 6).Select(xx => xx.Id);
```

`x` in subquery override by `x` in query. By change it's name, my problem is resolved.